# How to go to new line in index values of an array after each regular expression "\n" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in JavaScript I tried to find a solution to this challenge I searched on google for 4 days but I could not find any solution, maybe I don't know how to search for this problem!.

What I am trying to do is looping in an array of strings that each index value has more than one sentence and the end of each sentence has a newLine character `\n`. I want to find each sentence that ends with `\n` and write them separately in a new line. My goal is after reaching to this level insert each line inside a `p tag`.

```js
const Arr = ["Lorem ipsum dolor\n facilis obcaecati.\n tervis bigdole.\n", "sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.\n amet consectetur adipisicing\n", "Similique minima ea iure corrupti molestias?\n facilis obcaecati.\n fdloef obdcaecati.\n", "Aperiam enim ipsam debitis animi facere\n", "incidunt veritatis quia quos doloremque\n", "odio adipisci face octa bile obati.\n similique facilis obcaecati.\n"]

console.log(Arr.length)
```

Comment: You want to get each sentence and place it on an array?

Comment: Like this? Arr.flatMap(x => x.split('\n').filter(t => t.trim() !== ''));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this help (separating each sentence and placing it on a new array):

```
Arr.flatMap(x => x.split('\n').filter(t => t.trim() !== ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to archive but, if you really want to turn sentence who has \n into new line you just need to split it into new array

```js
const Arr = ["Lorem ipsum dolor\n facilis obcaecati.\n tervis bigdole.\n", "sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.\n amet consectetur adipisicing\n", "Similique minima ea iure corrupti molestias?\n facilis obcaecati.\n fdloef obdcaecati.\n", "Aperiam enim ipsam debitis animi facere\n", "incidunt veritatis quia quos doloremque\n", "odio adipisci face octa bile obati.\n similique facilis obcaecati.\n"]

newArr = [];
Arr.forEach(element => {
  nArr = element.split('\n');
  nArr.pop();
  nArr = nArr.map(function(str) {
    return str.trim();
  });
  newArr.push(nArr);
});
console.log(newArr) // all array who has \n
console.log(newArr.flat()) // merge all into new array
```

With that way you could get the new list array whhich has new line from group of array